# Closed form of this type $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^jj^n}{(2j+1)(2j+3){2j \choose j}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Given that, $$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^j\left(j-\frac{1}{3}\right)^3\left(j^2+j-1\right)}{(2j+1)(2j+3){2j \choose j}}=A\tag1$$

We have $A=2\pi+12+\frac{1}{3}?$

We can generalize the above $(1)$:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^jj^n}{(2j+1)(2j+3){2j \choose j}}=F(n)\tag2$$

I believe the closed for $(2)$ is

$$F(n)=(-1)^{n}(2n+1)-(-1)^n (2n-1)\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$$

How can we show that the proposed $(2)$ is correct?

Comment: No, $(2)$ is not correct.I doubt there's a closed form for the general sum.

Comment: Do you want $j$ starting at 0 or 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the expansion of [$\arcsin^2 t$](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inverse_trigonometric_functions&section=10#Infinite_series)
\begin{equation}
 \arcsin^2 t=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2p}t^{2p+2}}{(2p+1)(p+1)\binom{2p}{p}}
\end{equation} 
we can obtain by differentiation 
\begin{equation}
 2\frac{\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2p+1}t^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)\binom{2p}{p}}
\end{equation} 
Multiplying the above identity by $t$ and integrating, one obtains
\begin{equation}
 2\int_0^x\frac{t\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{2^{2p+1}x^{2p+3}}{(2p+1)(2p+3)\binom{2p}{p}}
\end{equation} 
We choose $x=\sqrt{y}/2$ and divide the identity by $y^{3/2}$ to write
\begin{equation}
 \frac{8}{y^{3/2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{y}/2}\frac{t\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{y^{p}}{(2p+1)(2p+3)\binom{2p}{p}}
\end{equation} 
Now, applying the operator $y\frac{d}{dy}$ $n$ times and taking the result at $y=2$ gives
\begin{equation}
 \left.\left[ y\frac{d}{dy}\right]^n\frac{8}{y^{3/2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{y}/2}\frac{t\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\right|_{y=2}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{p^{n}2^p}{(2p+1)(2p+3)\binom{2p}{p}}
\end{equation} 
The function can be evaluated as
\begin{equation}
 \frac{8}{y^{3/2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{y}/2}\frac{t\arcsin t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\frac{4}{y}-8\frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{y}{4}}}{y^{3/2}}\arcsin\left( \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2} \right)
\end{equation} 
The above result can be simplified by taking $z=\sqrt{y}/2$:
 \begin{equation}
 \left.\left[\frac{1}{2} z\frac{d}{dz}\right]^n
 \left[ \frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z^3}\arcsin z\right]
 \right|_{z=\sqrt{2}/2}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{p^{n}2^p}{(2p+1)(2p+3)\binom{2p}{p}}
\end{equation} 
As $\arcsin \left(\sqrt{2}/2\right)=\pi/4$ and since the successive applications of the operator on $z^{-2}$ and $z^{-3}\left( 1-z^2 \right)^k$ ($k$ is an integer) at $z=1/\sqrt{2}$ give rational results, we expect
\begin{equation}
 F(n)=a_n+b_n\pi
\end{equation} 
where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are rational. I could not find any simple expression for these coefficients  however. First few values are $F(n)=2-\pi/2,-3+\pi,5-3\pi/2,-7+5\pi/2,13-3\pi,-7+17\pi/2, 93+27\pi/2\cdots$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5,6\cdots$. They do not correspond to the propose formula as remarked by @Mariusz Iwaniuk in a comment.

With $z=\exp(t/2)$, we have $1/2zd/dz=d/dt$, and we can build the generating function for the $F(n)$:
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty F(n)\frac{t^n}{n!}=\phi\left( t-\ln2 \right)
\end{equation} 
where
\begin{equation}
 \phi\left( t-\ln 2 \right)=2e^{-3t/2}\left[ e^{t/2}-\sqrt{2-e^{t}}\arcsin\left(\frac{ e^{t/2}}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: (+1) Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I get (what I think are the correct results) by removing the multiplier of 2 from your generating function but getting $F(n)-(-1)^n$ from the generating function.  That makes the first 7 values $2-\frac{\pi }{2},\pi -3,5-\frac{3 \pi }{2},\frac{5 \pi }{2}-7,13-3 \pi ,\frac{17 \pi }{2}-7,93+\frac{27 \pi }{2}$.  Am I totally screwing up here?

Comment: @JimB You're right. Thank you for having pointed the typo which is now corrected.

Comment: In yours formula in Mathematica for `n=2`: `Expand[(z/2*D[1/z^2 - Sqrt[1 - z^2]/z^3*ArcSin[z], {z, 2}]) /. 
  z -> Sqrt[2]/2]` I have got: `13 Sqrt[2] - 4 Sqrt[2] π
`,but it should be: `5 - (3 π)/2` ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I think that for $n=2$ the expression reads $$\frac z2 \frac{d}{dz}\left[\frac z2 \frac{d}{dz} f(z)\right]$$ and not $\frac z2\frac{d^2}{dz^2} f(z)$.

Comment: @PaulEnta It works.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Too long for a comment.*

Just out of curiosity, I computed $$G_n=2(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^jj^n}{(2j+1)(2j+3){2j \choose j}}$$ and got the surprising results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 4-\pi  \\
 1 & 6-2 \pi  \\
 2 & 10-3 \pi  \\
 3 & 14-5 \pi  \\
 4 & 26-6 \pi  \\
 5 & 14-17 \pi  \\
 6 & 186+27 \pi  \\
 7 & -1042-380 \pi  \\
 8 & 10906+3399 \pi  \\
 9 & -119218-38057 \pi  \\
 10 & 1490042+474132 \pi  \\
 11 & -20706898-6591455 \pi  \\
 12 & 317327706+101008179 \pi  \\
 13 & -5315948530-1692119522 \pi  \\
 14 & 96656651578+30766766937 \pi  \\
 15 & -1895852523154-603468602105 \pi  \\
 16 & 39903246182426+12701597748834 \pi  \\
 17 & -897111926876722-285559595341037 \pi  \\
 18 & 21456828988070394+6829920793053567 \pi  \\
 19 & -544015833214835410-173165617952800580 \pi  \\
 20 & 14574701046924559066+4639271431409321739 \pi 
\end{array}
\right)$$ where, as already said in comments and answers, no pattern seems to appear.